# Значение input в адресной строке

Tags: html, html5

Не знаю, возможно ли это, но как сделать так, чтобы если я перешел по адресу

типа *ru.ru/russia.html?input22=sometext*

Тогда бы в `<input name="input22">` было введено **sometext**

Comment: возможно сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, возможно.

```
const paramsString = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&');
const params = paramsString.map(string => string.split('='));
params.forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const input = document.querySelector(`input[name=${key}]`);
    if (input) input.value = value;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает. Я Вам очень благодарен!